# Javascript code to extract a number from last of a string

Tags: javascript

I need a javascript code to extract number from string like "pushedProductType0".

Comment: I would use jQuery for this for sure!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
alert( "pushedProductType0".match(/\d/) )
```

Comment: This will get the 1st number, and only single digits. You should do `.match(/\d+/g)`

Comment: I agree with `/\d+/` but the global flag is not appropriate as it would return an array. This is just a starter for 10, the question is not specific enough to develop any further

Comment: Any hint on getting the `last one` ? Here's my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059054/get-and-replace-the-last-number-on-a-string-with-javascript-or-jquery